# Solutions for inequality $\frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{1-x} \gt 0$

Tags: calculus, inequality

How to find all real solutions for $$\frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{1-x} \gt 0$$
I came up with $\frac{1}{x(1-x)} \gt 0$ implies $x(1-x)>0$ and finally ended with $0<x<1$ but the answer provided was $0<x<1$ or $x>1$. I tried sample values for $x>1$ but they don't satisfy the inequality.

Comment: Fixed my solution.

Comment: The answer provided was wrong.

Answer (score 4):

It should be $\frac{1}{x(1-x)} \gt 0$ thus, $x(1-x)>0$ and so, $0 < x < 1$ is the only solution.

Comment: how come spivak added x>1

Comment: @PanchixRegen you should come up $\frac{1}{x(1-x)} \gt 0$ not $\frac{1}{x(x-1)} \gt 0$ that causes the mistake

Comment: i editted my answer, typo only

Comment: @PanchixRegen your end is true, however your first stage of solution that begins with "I came up with... " is false and I have fixed it above my solution.

Comment: oh sorry. Fixed it

Answer (score 1):

The function $$f(x)=\frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{1-x}$$ may only change where it's not defined, i.e., for $x\in\{0,1\}$ or in its zeroes, which don't exist.  Now check the corresponding three intervals $(-\infty,0)$, $(0,1)$ and $(1,\infty)$ for positivity.